# How to combine near same item by SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data in database:

```
id user 
1 zhangsan 
2 zhangsan 
3 zhangsan 
4 lisi 
5 lisi 
6 lisi 
7 zhangsan 
8 zhangsan
```

I want keep order, and combine near same user items, how to do it?
When I use shell script, I will(data in file test.):

```
cat test|cut -d " " -f2|uniq -c
```

this will get result as:

```
   3 zhangsan 
   3 lisi 
   2 zhangsan
```

But how to do it use sql?

Comment: Shouldn't your result be `4 lisi`?

Comment: You want to know how many count(id) of each user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try:

```
SET @name:='',@num:=0;

SELECT id,
       @num:= if(@name = user, @num, @num + 1) as number,
       @name := user as user
FROM foo
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

This gives:

```
+------+--------+------+
| id   | number | user |
+------+--------+------+
|    1 |      1 | a    |
|    2 |      1 | a    |
|    3 |      1 | a    |
|    4 |      2 | b    |
|    5 |      2 | b    |
|    6 |      2 | b    |
|    7 |      3 | a    |
|    8 |      3 | a    |
+------+--------+------+
```

So then you can try:

```
SET @name:='',@num:=0;

SELECT COUNT(*) as count, user
FROM (
SELECT @num:= if(@name = user, @num, @num + 1) as number,
       @name := user as user
FROM foo
ORDER BY id ASC
) x
GROUP BY number;
```

Which gives

```
+-------+------+
| count | user |
+-------+------+
|     3 | a    |
|     3 | b    |
|     2 | a    |
+-------+------+
```

(I called my table `foo` and also just used names `a` and `b` because I was too lazy to write `zhangsan` and `lisi` over and over).

Comment: +1. My idea exactly, only I would have used `FROM foo, (SELECT @name:='', @num:=0)` instead of `SET @name:='',@num:=0;`

Answer (score 0):

if in oracle, you can do like below.

```
SELECT NAME,
       num - lagnum
  FROM (SELECT lagname,
               NAME,
               num,
               nvl(lag(num) over(ORDER BY num), 0) lagnum
          FROM (SELECT id,
                       lag(NAME) over(ORDER BY ID) lagname,
                       NAME,
                       lead(NAME) over(ORDER BY ID) leadname,
                       ROWNUM num
                  FROM (SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY ID))
         WHERE (lagname = NAME AND (NAME <> leadname OR leadname IS NULL))
            OR (lagname IS NULL AND NAME <> leadname)
            OR (lagname <> NAME AND leadname IS NULL)
         ORDER BY ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

if in sql server, oracle, db2...

```
    with x as(  
select c.*, rn = row_number() over (order by c.id)
  from test c 
  left join test n
    on c.[user] = n.[user]
   and c.[id] + 1 = n.[id]   
 where n.id is null
)
select a.[user], a.id - coalesce(b.id, 0) 
  from x a
  left join x b
    on a.rn = b.rn + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

A little improvement to the selected answer would be not to have to define those variables. So this query can be solved in just a single statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, user
FROM (
    SELECT @num := @num + (@name != user) as number,
           @name := user as user
    FROM t, (select @num := 0, @name := '') as s
    ORDER BY id
) x
GROUP BY number
```

Output:

```
| CNT |     USER |
|-----|----------|
|   3 | zhangsan |
|   3 |     lisi |
|   2 | zhangsan |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43e3c/1)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is to COUNT(ID):

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM table GROUP BY user
```

Comment: This gives global counts. The OP is after counts of contiguous usernames when ordered by ID (see how `zanghsan` appears twice).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this in sql without doing some sort of sequential (iterative) analysis.  Remember sql is set operation language.