# Selecting number of sequential records

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get number of rows per each subsequence.

The initial table could look like this:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | value       |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | a           |
|  2 | b           |
|  3 | b           |
|  4 | c           |
|  5 | a           |
|  6 | a           |
|  7 | a           |
|  8 | a           |
|  9 | c           |
|  10| c           |
+----+-------------+
```

The query should return the count of items for each sequence of values:

```
+----+-------------+
| value | count    |
+----+-------------+
|  a    | 1        |
|  b    | 2        |
|  c    | 1        |
|  a    | 4        |
|  c    | 2        |
+-------+----------+
```

So far I haven't been able to come up with a solution, at least not fast enough for large tables. Ideally there would be a "group by" statement that doesn't mess up the order of records.

Comment: This is called run-length encoding.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172006/how-to-combine-near-same-item-by-sql

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT value, count(*) FROM (
  SELECT value,
    (CASE WHEN @v != value THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i END) gid,
     @v := value FROM myTable, (SELECT @v:='', @i := 0) vars
) tbl
GROUP BY gid
```

Comment: I think this is VERY CLOSE... Only thing.  On the change from every record AFTER the first, the @i will be the count starting the next cycle.  I would change your ELSE to  ELSE @i := 1  ... to indicate it is being reset back to 1 as the start of the new ID just coming in.

Comment: @DRapp: Did you try it? I think it works as the OP wants as is, and that your suggestion would break it. You need a constantly increasing counter, or you will group together equal values separated by groups of different values.

Comment: you are correct... missed it, and your COUNT is the actual counter where your "i" value is the force break between each cyclical change between values... misinterpreted your "i" variable